# Publish check if the edited content has HTML "div"

Tags: plugins, hooks

I need to check if a post content has a divider ID name when a post is published so that I change some value in a custom database table.

The problem is that the `publish_post` hook or whatever other one I have tried always check the old post content but not the new updated one, means that I have to publish the post twice to get a correct test:

```
add_action( 'publish_post', 'psidPaginationFunction', 99, 0 );
function psidPaginationFunction() {
    global $post;
    global $wpdb;

    $table_name = 'wp_psid_custom_navigation';
    setup_postdata( $post->ID );
    $content = $post->post_content;
    $permalink = get_permalink( $post->ID );

    if ( strpos( $content, 'psid-mainPost' ) !== false ) {
        $wpdb->insert($table_name,
            array(
                'post_id' => $post->ID, //replaced non-existing variables $lq_name, and $lq_descrip, with the ones we set to collect the data - $name and $description
                'is_parent' => '1',
                'is_children' => '0',
                'permalink' => $permalink ,
            ),
            array(
                '%d',
                '%d',
                '%d',
                '%s'
            )
        );  
    }
}
```

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/publish_post - what about when you access the value from the args; $id, $post? You really shouldn't be using globals. See the example on the link.

Comment: I used the example on that link earlier today, but even if all my debug mods are active in wp-config, that always showed me a blank page with url  admin:post.php,

Comment: this only was resolved by declaring/defining the global vars like you see here inside my function

Comment: Maybe use in combination with update_post hooks https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_update_post

Comment: the same example that you just showed : ( sending an email when a post is published ) wan't work with any hook in my case, as i just tried all possible hooks ( action s and filters )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think going back to the source is the best way to resolve that issue,**This is a timing / synchronization problem as i can see**, so when i use sql query to read the updated value in the database i finally get things working correctly, 
**here is what i have added to get the UPDATED content :**

```
$querystr = "SELECT $wpdb->posts.post_content FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE $wpdb->posts.ID = $post->ID";
$content = $wpdb->get_row($querystr, OBJECT);
$content = $content->post_content;
```

Comment: any body comes with a good solution ??